# Efficient implementation of the Clifford group for $n$ qubits

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, quantum-computation

I'm looking for an efficient implementation of the Clifford group $\mathcal{C}_n$
of $n$ qubits.
The Clifford group $\mathcal{C}_n$ has stucture $(2_+^{1+2n} \circ C_8).Sp(2,n)$, 
where  $2_+^{1+2n}$ denotes an extraspecial 2 group of $+$ type, $C_8$ the
cyclic group of order 8, and $Sp(2n,2)$ a symplectic group over the binary field. 
Here "$\circ$" means the central product.

The Clifford group $\mathcal{C}_n$ can be used for the simulation of quantum 
computing with $n$ qubits and a restricted set of qubit gates in polynomial time,
see e.g. [1]. It has a unitary complex representation of dimension $2^n$, 
see e.g. [2].  Quantum theorists use an explicit construction 
$\rho$ of that representation of $\mathcal{C}_n$ based on Pauli matrices, 
see [1]. Vectors in $\rho$ are called **state vectors**. In [1] the group 
$\mathcal{C}_n$ is generated by the qubit gates CNOT, Phase, and Hadamard.
These gates operate (repeatedly) on the state vectors starting at a certain 
unit vector $e_0 = |0 \ldots 0 \rangle$. Let $V_0$ be the image of $e_0$ 
under the operation of $\mathcal{C}_n$ in the state vector space.

I need an  implementation of representation
$\rho$ that supports the following operations:

- Multiplication, inversion, and test for equality in $\mathcal{C}_n$.
- Operation of an element of $\mathcal{C}_n$ on a state vector in $V_0$.
- Output of an entry of the matrix representing 
  an element of  $\mathcal{C}_n$.
- Output of an entry of a state vector in $V_0$.
- Some kind of qubit measurement applied to a state vector in $V_0$,
  as in [1].

Entries of matrices and vectors are with respect to the representation $\rho$
in [1]. Runtime should be polynomial in $n$.

I have some concrete ideas for such an implementation.

My question is:

**Has anybody implemented  a similar representation of $\mathcal{C}_n$  before?**

Note that the representation in [1] implements state vectors in $V_0$
(up to a scalar multiple), and operation of $\mathcal{C}_n$ on $V_0$, but not 
the computation of entries of group elements or state vectors. In [1] elements of
$\mathcal{C}_n$ cannot easily be tested for equality. I also need to 
distingiush between scalar multiples of a state vector, which is irrelevant 
in quantum theory.

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406196

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001038

Comment: quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com suitable for this question

Comment: This is now crossposted at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5164/efficient-implementation-of-the-clifford-group-for-n-qubits